# How to move a document with tracked changes in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

When I track changes on a Word 2007 document and then copy the document into another document, either the changes are not shown or the entire document is shown as a change.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do.  You are not going to be able to "transfer" the changes to a particular document into another document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the changes to be propogated across two documents then you need to make an actual copy of the document via "Save as" or by Copy-Paste from **Explorer**, not Word.

As mentioned Word copy and paste copies only content, a full physical file copy will keep all of the file contents including the change data.

Answer (score 1):

Turn track changes off in your source document, then copy the marked up text.  Go to your second document and ensure track changes is off before pasting.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  When you copy/cut content from one document into another document... the 2nd document only sees the "paste"... as a change.  It will not see any changes made to the 1st document.